# 1st Yr Probability: what is wrong with my approach? (using indicator RVs)

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Joe’s iPod has $500$ different songs, consisting of $50$ albums of $10$ songs each. He listens to $11$ random songs on his iPod, with all songs equally likely and chosen independently (so repetitions may occur).
>
> A pair of songs is a “match” if they are from the same album. If, say, the 1st,
> 3rd, and 7th songs are all from the same album, this counts as $3$ matches. Among
> the $11$ songs he listens to, how many matches are there on average? (Simplify.)

**My attempt**

Let $X = $ # of matches among the $11$ songs

Let $X = X_1 + ... X_{50}$  where $X_i =$ # of matches among the $11$ songs from album $i$

$$ E[X] = E[X_1 + ... + X_{50}] = 50E[X_1] $$

To find $E[X_1]$ I will condition on if there are at least $2$ matches of the first album in the $11$ songs.

$$ E[X_1] = E[X_1 \mid \text{at least 2}] P(\text{at least 2}) +  E[X_1 \mid \text{0 or 1}] P(\text{0 or 1}) $$

So the second term goes to zero since each $X_i$ is in $[2,11]$.

$$ P(\text{at least 2}) = 1 - P(\text{first album not in 11 songs}) - P(\text{first album shows up once in 11})$$

$$ =1 - \left( \frac{49}{50} \right)^{11} - 11 \left( \frac{1}{50} \right) \left( \frac{49}{50} \right)^{10} \approx 0.01951263$$

$ E[X_1 \mid \text{at least 2}] = 2 + Y $ where $Y \sim Binomial(11-2, 1/50)$ and so

$$ E[X_1 \mid \text{at least 2}] = 2 + 9/50 $$

Finally

$$ E[X] = 50 ( 2 + 9/50) 0.01951263 \approx 2.1268768591 $$

However the answer is $1.1$. The book solution below uses the $11$ choose $2$ possible pairs as indicator RVs... berry clever... it makes sense to me and is superior to what I'm doing. But what is wrong with my approach above? Thanks.

**My question:** What is wrong with my approach, where am I going off the rails?

---

Book solution:

[image]

Comment: I have to run off and do an errand but I will return this afternoon and will carefully read any answers, or maybe a comment suffices to clear my confusion. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: If the first and second are songs are from the first album, but no others are from that album, that's one match.  The example they use is confusing.  If songs $(i,j,k)$ are all on the same album that is three matches because $ij,ik,jk$ are all matches.  This meaning is clear from the calculation they provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method works if you use the correct definition of "match" (though it is harder than the official method).

From the official solution, we see that a "match" means "a pair $(i,j)$ such that the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ song are from the same album.  Thus if songs $(i,j,k)$ are all from the same album we have three matches since $(i,j), (i,k), (j,k)$ are all matches.

Note:  the example given in the problem statement is misleading.  It would be better to look at the case where the four songs $(i,j,k,l)$ are all on the same album.  In that case there are $6$ matches:  $(i,j), (i,k), (i,l), (j,k), (j,l), (k,l)$.  In general, if there are $n$ songs from a given album there are $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ matches.

To use your method we compute $E[X_i]$ via the binomial distribution. We get $$E[X_i]=\sum_{n=0}^{n=11} \frac {n(n-1)}2\times \binom {11}n\times \left( \frac 1{50}\right)^n\times \left( \frac {49}{50} \right)^{11-n}=.022$$

The answer is then $$E=50\times .022=1.1$$ confirming the official solution.

Comment: Thanks your explanation is excellent. You're right, my critical error was not understanding the book's defn of match, ie 4 songs from one album means 6 matches. I think the book was trying to help guide me to using the 11 choose 2 pairs as indicator RVs but I didn't see that. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, in the real world if someone were to ask me, what is the expected number of "matches" in 11 songs, I think they would not use the book's definition of "match." So for example I think for most people, 4 songs from one album would be 4 "matches."

Comment: @HJ_beginner  Oh, I understand.  That's why I said their use of the term was misleading.  The picked the worst possible number to illustrate the definition.